# Trouble loading DLL in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, windows, dll, loadlibrary

I am having some troubles to load a DLL in a Windows console application I am coding for a class project.I don't know why it doesn't load the library file.

Before I call LoadLibrary where I have the error, I define this before main:

```
#include "lomo2.h"
```

and

```
HINSTANCE cargaDLL;
```

Also I have tried changing HINSTANCE to HMODULE type but it is useless.

After that in main I try to import the DLL that is located in main:

```
cargaDLL =  LoadLibrary("C:\\lomo2.dll");
if (cargaDLL == NULL){
    PERROR ("Error en la carga de la libreria\n");
    Sleep(2000);
    exit (1);
}
```

When I call LoadLibrary I have also tried to use a relative path like "LoadLibrary(.\my dll directory\lomo2.dll)" but it doesn't work at all.

The result is the message where it says there has been an error while linking the library, in PERROR.

Checking the error with `GetLastError()` it says it cannot find the specified module.

I hope you can help me to solve this problem.
Thnaks.

Comment: Are there any dependent dlls?

Comment: No.They have only provided the header lomo2.h and the dll file lomo2.dll and it should work.No other files are needed for this program.

Comment: I would use `GetLastError()` to get the error code when the `cargaDLL == NULL`

Comment: When you call LoadLibrary and specify a relative path, remember that in Visual Studio, the working directory is the project's directory by default. And I guess you expect it to be the target directory (${TargetDir}).

Comment: I am not using now a relative path because it didn't work.The dll is in root of C: and that is the path I am passing to the function as in the code I wrote above

Comment: Did you build `lomo2.dll` on your computer? I mean perhaps `lomo2.dll` was built with a different version of Visual Studio.

Comment: It was provided by our teacher so I think he compiled it in his pc.Should I recompile it? if so,how I do that?

Comment: Make sure you are using the same version of Visual Studio as the teacher expects.

Comment: He didn't told us to use any version nor what version was using him.I am trying to contact him by email but it will take some days.Should I build it?

Comment: ***Should I build it?*** Most likely no.

Comment: Time to check on the `GetLastError()`. Windows will tell you the problem.

Comment: It says it cannot find the specified module

Comment: Try LoadLibraryA()

Comment: Turn on loader snaps. `lomo2.dll` may depend on another DLL, and that other DLL is missing.

Comment: try this tool http://www.dependencywalker.com/ and see what exactly is missing

Comment: To enable loader snaps, open the Start menu and type *gflags*. Pick the appropriate bitness in case you get both x86 and x64 offered. The option *Show loader snaps* is on the *System Registry* tab. @Exceptyon: Dependency Walker is pretty much dead. It hasn't been updated in years, and fails more often than it helps. There are better tools around (e.g. DUMPBIN).

Comment: Is the dll a 32bit or 64bit dll? Is your project configuration the same? You cannot load a 32 bit dll from a 64bit process or vice versa.

Comment: @ChrisBecke: You cannot execute 32-bit code in a 64-bit process and vice versa. You can load a 32-bit DLL into a 64-bit process (and vice versa) if that doesn't lead to running any code.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem was solved by changing the character set from "Unicode" to "No Set" in the Visual Studio project settings.

Thanks all of you for your answers.

Comment: Had you set the *Character Set* to *Unicode*, the code in your question wouldn't even compile. So either you lied in your question, or this is not an answer. Besides, choosing the worst imaginable character encoding for a new project is not ever a solution.

Comment: I didn't lie.The config of Visual Studio was the default so I didn't set the Character Set to Unicode,it was set by default.And that is why it wouldn't compile.So the answer for my problem was what I said (my teacher told me about that could be the reason for that problem) or changing the function LoadLibrary to LoadLibraryW.

Comment: If you left the default settings (Unicode) then `LoadLibrary("C:\\lomo2.dll");` will not compile. Since you are talking about linker errors, it **did** compile, so you aren't telling the truth. You either didn't use Unicode character encoding or there were no linker errors (but rather compiler errors). At any rate, a question containing the phrase *"it doesn't work at"* needs improvement.

Comment: All Visual Studio new project must be UNICODE

Answer (score 2):

I would use something like [Process Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processmonitor) which will show you what the program is doing when it attempts to load the DLL.

I had a similar scenario occur with me and what was happening with me was that Windows did not find the DLL in the local location so it started looking through **well known** locations.  One of these was to search the PATH, in my instance the PATH contains a location that was inaccessible, this caused the search to stop and the DLL not to load.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code:

```
HMODULE cargaDLL;
cargaDLL =  LoadLibrary(L"C:\\lomo2.dll");
```

Always work with UNICODE as the type of the project. 
Using relative path is better for other reasons (using "c:\lomo.dll" will work).
If you collaborate with other programmers on a project, it is better to assume all files will be placed in one folder and use relative path to this folder.